# Qualities of inheritors of Firdous

Tags: tafseer, jannah

There are six qualities of inheritors of Firdaus (Paradise) have been given in the start of Surah Al-Mumenoon. Can someone them briefly

Comment: To me this looks like a rhetorical question.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Quran, Surah #23, Ayahs 1- 11](https://quran.com/23):

> Certainly will the believers have succeeded. They **who are during their
>   prayer humbly submissive**. And they **who turn away from ill speech**. And
>   they **who are observant of zakah**. And they **who guard their private
>   parts**. Except from their wives or those their right hands possess, for
>   indeed, they will not be blamed .But whoever seeks beyond that, then
>   those are the transgressors .And they **who are to their trusts and
>   their promises attentive**. And they **who carefully maintain their
>   prayers**. Those are the inheritors. Who will inherit al-Firdaus. They
>   will abide therein eternally.